# Does DateTime.toFileTimeUtc actually work? I can't produce a UTC filetime

Tags: .net, powershell

I noticed that no matter what I do, `tofiletimeutc()` always returns the same as `toFileTime()`. I need to produce a UTC timestamp. So I tried this experiment in Powershell:

```
(get-date).tofiletime();
(get-date).touniversalTime().tofiletimeutc();
(get-date).tofiletimeutc();
```

and the output is:

```
129757574870723241
129757574870723241
129757574870723241
```

(All 3 are identical, local-time stamps. Time zone is set to Pacific).

`(get-date).touniversalTime()` works as expected, but no matter which "to-utc" function I use, it is for some reason converted back into local time. Does anyone see what is going on?

Comment: It's possible I'm being confused by this website. http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php . The value it gives me is equal to my local time. The website is... not aware of my timezone, right? Text Date on this website is UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does work all three values you see are filetimes "in UTC".

Background:

The Windows [FILETIME is defined as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC)."

Both `DateTime.ToFileTime()` and `DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc()` return a UTC-based value.
In fact, `DateTime.ToFileTime()` is implemented as `DateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToFileTimeUtc()`.

**Update** Concerning the comments:

The value is always the same, as said above, what you "see" when converting it back to a `DateTime` instance and dumping that, on which method you use:

Those two return the "same" DateTime value with `DateTimeKind.Utc` and the `DateTime` value "adjusted" to UTC.

```
[datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc((get-date).ToFileTime())
[datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc((get-date).ToFileTimeUtc())
```

Those two return the "same" DateTime value with `DateTimeKind.Local` and the `DateTime` value adjusted to local.

```
[datetime]::FromFileTime((get-date).ToFileTime())
[datetime]::FromFileTime((get-date).ToFileTimeUtc())
```

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question. The OP is claiming he is still getting a _local_ time back.

Comment: So DateTime.ToFileTime() and DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc() always produce identical output? If not, is when is there a difference?

Comment: @RobLevine Yes, it did not answer the question (hopefully the update does better), however I think the OPs assertion that the three values are "in local time" is wrong to begin with (which I tried pointing out with the initial revision of the answer), potentially so because he _may_ have used `[datetime]::FromFileTime()` to convert them to something printable.

Comment: @VoidStar they do produce identical output "a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).", so they are in UTC. What method did you use to "print" them to see if they are local or utc?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm no longer as confused. I used this website silisoftware.com/tools/date.php to see if what I have is local or UTC, which was probably my mistake. I thought it was a simple math conversion this thing could handle. I put in my filetime into it and I don't get the UTC text date back, so I guess it's doing something other than I expected.